# $interval nested inside ng-click listener is called when browser navigates back

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a button that, on-click (ng-click), calls $interval. If I navigate back to the state that includes the button with the browsers back button, $interval is called again. This is a problem because the interval is a timer for $state.go() and changes the state again.

My code is below. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I might rewrite this to allow backward navigation via the browser without triggering $interval. Thanks in advance.

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app')
    .component('splash', {
      templateUrl: '/templates/splash.template.html',
      controller: SplashController
    })

  SplashController.$inject = ['SplashService', '$http', '$stateParams', '$state', '$interval']

  function SplashController(SplashService, $http, $stateParams, $state, $interval) {
    console.log("you are in the splash Controller")
    const vm = this
    vm.$onInit = onInit
    vm.userAuth = {}
    function onInit() {
      // $(".button-collapse").sideNav()
    }
    vm.logIn = function() {
      console.log('userAuth: ', vm.userAuth)
      SplashService.logIn(vm.userAuth)

    }

    vm.moveLotus = function() {
      let lotus_top = document.getElementById('animated-login-top')
      let lotus_bottom = document.getElementById('animated-login-bottom')
      // let menuIcon = document.getElementById('menuIcon')
      // menuIcon.style.display = 'none'
      lotus_top.className = 'animated-login-top-move move-lotus-top'
      lotus_bottom.className = 'lotus-login-bottom-pulse move-lotus-bottom'
      // wait 2 seconds and then &state.go('feed')
      let goTo = function(state) {
        $state.go(state)
      }
      $interval(function() {
        goTo('feed')
      }, 2500)
    }
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row demoRow center">
    <a href="#" ng-click="$ctrl.moveLotus()">Demo Site</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at this case `$interval` still works, you should manually stop it via `$interval.cancel` when `$scope.$on('$destroy'...`:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $interval) {        
    var stopTime = $interval(function() {      
      console.log(new Date());
    }, 1000);

    $scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
      $interval.cancel(stopTime);
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <button ng-click='show=!show'>{{show ? 'Destroy' : 'Create'}} controller</button>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl' ng-if='show'>        
    controller
  </div>  
</div>
```

P.S. At your particular case, probably, it is better to use `$timeout` instead of `$interval`.

Comment: This isn't working. I can't manually destroy as the problem occurs when the browser navigates back to the state. I've even tried running ```$interval.cancel(goToFeed)``` in my $onInit function for state load, but this doesn't work either.